# PyQt5 run-time error when closing popup message

Tags: python, pyqt5

time error when I'm trying to close the app. Here's the code. I'm using pyqt5 designer.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QMessageBox, QGridLayout
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
def setupUi(self, Dialog):
    #Form Dialog
    grid = QGridLayout()
    Dialog.setLayout(grid)
    Dialog.setObjectName("LoginForm")
    Dialog.resize(640, 480)

    #Button Exit
    self.btnEsc = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
```

I'm having trouble on this part of the code "(self.closeEvent)"

```
    self.btnEsc.clicked.connect(self.closeEvent)

    self.btnEsc.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 310, 75, 61))
    self.btnEsc.setObjectName("btnEsc")

    #Form translate
    self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
```

when I close this part(running), it pops up a message "Python has stopped working"

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
    reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
                                        "Are you sure to quit?",
                                        QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)

    if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()
```

I just want a customized for exit button, please help....

Comment: change `self.btnEsc.clicked.connect(self.closeEvent)` to `self.btnEsc.clicked.connect(self.close)`

Comment: Please fix you indentation. Please also include the part where you init your application.

Comment: events should not be called directly, you should call close, and that method will call closeEvent correctly.

Comment: @eyllanesc already did that part and I'm having an error if I change it to (self.close)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5-tools\UITestCodes\dialog.py", line 120, in <module>
    ui.setupUi(main)
  File "C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5-tools\UITestCodes\dialog.py", line 90, in setupUi
    self.btnEsc.clicked.connect(self.close)
AttributeError: 'Ui_Dialog' object has no attribute 'close'

Comment: @MusicLover read http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code